# how to display an img with a class in javascript using document.createElement("img")?

Tags: javascript, css

```
document.createElement("img")
```

how can I set a class to the img element in js?

Comment: `var elmImg = document.createElement("img"); elmImg.className = 'foo';

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change an element's class with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/how-can-i-change-an-elements-class-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

To add the class to all of the images on your page with jQuery:

```
$("img").addClass("imagedropshadow")
```

Without jQuery is is not very difficult either:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var i;

for(i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].className += " imagedropshadow";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

save the element as a variable

```
let element = document.createElement('img');
```

and then:

```
element.className = 'someClaasName';
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a class to an element using javascript use `.className` => `el.className = 'listItem'`. Here we add the class name `listItem` to an element.

***MDN: The className property of the Element interface gets and sets the value of the class attribute of the specified element.***

```js
let img = document.createElement("img");
img.src= 'https://www.imagesource.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Rio.jpg';
img.className = 'myclassname';

document.body.append(img)

console.log(img)
```

```css
.myclassname {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
}
```

Comment: @nondoe Glad to hear! Feel free to accept the answer if it has assisted with your issue!